# Функция для получения отрицательных элементов массива

Tags: массивы, java, функции

В функции `main()` проинициализировать одномерный массив вещественных чисел. Создать функцию, которая принимает в качестве параметра массив, находит количество отрицательных элементов этого массива, создает новый массив необходимой размерности , заполняет его отрицательными элементами и возвращает новый массив. Результат вывести на экран.
Вот то что сделала я:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = { 11, 2, 4, 3, 5, -2, -8, -1, 9, 0 };
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] < 0)
            k++;
    }
    int j = 0;
    int[] b = new int[k];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] < 0) {
            b[j] = a[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    for (j = 0; j < b.length; j++)
        System.out.print(b[j] + " ");
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так Вы все уже сделали, нужно только часть кода вынести в отдельную функцию, а затем вызвать ее в методе main:

```
public static int[] func(int[] a) {
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] < 0)
            k++;
    }
    int j = 0;
    int[] b = new int[k];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] < 0) {
            b[j] = a[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    return b;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = { 11, 2, 4, 3, 5, -2, -8, -1, 9, 0 };
    int[] b = func( a );
    for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++)
        System.out.print(b[j] + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double[] a = { 1.1, 2.3, -5.6, -8.0, 9.7, -63 };
        double[] b = negativeArray(a);

        for (double x : b) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }

    }

    public static double[] negativeArray(double[] a) {
        ArrayList<Double> arr = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
            if (a[i] < 0) {
                arr.add(a[i]);
            }
        }

        double[] rez = new double[arr.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
            rez[i] = (double) arr.get(i);
        }

        return rez;
    }
}
```